# Flask - Using external blueprints

Tags: python, flask, pybossa

I am working on a big flask project, which supports `flask-plugins`. I need to add a feature which allows the user to upload files from his own PC. As I did not want to edit the core code of the server, I thought of adding this functionality by creating a plugin.

There is a blueprint already present in the core code by the name of `blueprint` as follows -

**pybossa/views/projects.py**

```
blueprint = Blueprint('projects', __name__)
```

And it is registered and has a `url_prefix` set in *core.py* -

**pybossa/core.py**

```
from pybossa.views.projects.py import blueprint as projects
app.register_blueprint(projects, '/projects')
```

Now I have a plugin called *testUploader*, and I am importing the blueprint 'projects' as follows -

**pybossa/plugins/testUploader/views.py**

```
from pybossa.view.projects import blueprint

@blueprint.route('/test')
def testUpload():
    return("Hello World")
```

As you can see, I have created a new blueprint route `/test`

But when I go to `localhost:5000/projects/test`, I get 404 page not found.

**Why is the route not working?**

Comment: Did you try running this? For instance, the handler function for the `/test` route has a syntax error (no parentheses). Also, what you're registering as blueprint is `projects` but that isn't the name of the blueprint declared earlier, where's `projects` coming from? Finally, `register_blueprint` only takes one positional argument (besides `self`).